# Electric dipole moment (EDM) and dilogarithm with complex argument

Tags: quantum-field-theory, computational-physics, dipole-moment, cp-violation, analyticity

In the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.1385  it's calculated the electron electric dipole moment (eEDM) in terms of a function $f_1(x)$ defined as

$$
f_1(x) = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1 - 4x}}\left[Li_2\left(1 - \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 4x}}{2x}\right) - Li_2\left(1 - \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - 4x}}{2x}\right)   \right], \quad Li_2(z) = -\int_0^z\frac{ln(1 - u)}{u}du.
$$

In a footnote of the paper, it's is said that even for $x > 1/4$, the dilogarithm $Li_2$ is real and analytic.

Hence, I've got 2 questions here:

1) I'm trying to do the **numerical** computation of $Li_2$ with a C++ programme that can only perform integrations of real integrands. Is there a way to use that for the case $z \in \mathbb{C}$ (i.e., $x>1/4$), taking into account that the dilogarithm should be allegedly real?

2) All in all, the eEDM is depending on $f_1(x)$ that appart from the dilogarithm, it depends on $\sqrt{1 - 4x}$ as prefactor. This implies that for $x>1/4$, that prefactor is complex... providing a complex eEDM?

The case $x>1/4$ is not physically impossible. The article works with $x = (m_{top}/m_{Higgs})^2 > 1$, so $z\in\mathbb{C}$ cannot be excluded.

Comment: The dilogarithms aren’t real for $x>1/4$; they’re complex. $f_1$ is real because the difference of the dilogarithms is imaginary.

Comment: I suggest using a computer algebra program that can evaluate $\text{Li}_2(z)$ for complex $z$. Why evaluate special functions with custom C++ that doesn’t even understand complex numbers?

Comment: @SuperCiocia that's other of my problems, I can't 100% know because paper doesn't tell but my internet research suggests me that it is complex

Comment: *In a footnote of the paper, it's is said that even for $x > 1/4$, the dilogarithm $Li_2$ is real and analytic.* This is not at all what the footnote says.

Comment: @G.Smith but the papers says the opposite, or am I misunderstanding something? And C++ knmows what complex numbers are since the library cmath.h exists. But what program would you suggest (if you know other different from Mathematica)?

Comment: This is not really a physics problem but it your programme can only do real integrand, you can just split the integrand into the real and imaginary parts, and do the integration on each part independently.

Comment: @Vicky Read the footnote again. It says $f_1$ is real, not Li$_2$.

Comment: @G.Smith Oh, I thought it was because of the $Li_2$. Ok, so the idea would be to calculate only the imaginary parts, right? But I'm not sure the real parts cancel out, because they are of the form: $\mbox{Re}[Li_2] \sim \int_0^1 ln(1 - 2tr\cos \phi + (tr)^2)dt/t$ with $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\phi$ the phase of the $Li_2$'s argument. In $f_1$ those two pases are not the same

Comment: I think that should work for $x>1/4$.

Comment: Do you have to use this code for $f_1$ in a larger C++ program?

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, why?Btw I edited my previous comment on your solution

Comment: Just trying to understand why you are doing things this way.

Comment: I tend to use *Mathematica*. It makes things like this completely trivial. You could evaluate $f_1$ to arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the footnote says

> Note that the loop function $f_1(x)$ is real and analytic even for $x >1/4$.
> In particular, in the limit $x\rightarrow \infty$, one has $f_1(x) = \ln x+ 2 +\mathcal{O}(1/\sqrt{x})$.

If you plot $f_1(x)$ you actually see:

[image]

from which you can see that "$f_1(x)$ is real" means that $x>0$. Which physically makes sense given the definition of $x = (m_{\mathrm{top}}/m_{\mathrm{Higgs}})^2$ and assuming real masses.

You can also verify the limit for large $x$:

[image]

The reason they specify the $x>1/4$ region is because the dilogaritm is complex for $x>1/4$. But, as mentioned in the comments, the *difference* of these two dilogarithms multiplied by the pre-factor is real (for $x>0$).

Finally, even if you were working for a complex $f_1(x)$, you can just write it as:
$$ f_1(x) = v(x) + \mathrm{i}w(x), $$ and make your C++ programme perform real integration on $v$ and $w$ individually.

Comment: Ok, one last remark: the real part of $Li_2$ is of the form $\sim \int_0^1 ln(1 - 2tr\cos\phi + (tr)^2)dt/t$. But because of the only difference among the two dilogarithms is that the imaginary part of their arguments would be the same up to sign, and the cosine is insensitive to the sign of $\phi$, the real parts cancel out. Right?

Comment: Where do you get that expression for the real prat of Li2? Which equation is it in the paper?

Comment: It is not in the paper. It is in this one https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00692071 DOI https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00692071

Comment: Do you have the arxiv link for that?

Comment: I don't find it, but I gave you the DOI

Comment: That paper is behind a paywall.

Comment: Yeah I can't really go around the paywall. But anyway, the *difference* of **these** dilogarithms is real, because their arguments are different. So adjust your formulae accordingly.

Comment: No, the difference is imaginary.

Comment: Yes sorry. I meant the whole $f_1(x)$ is real

Comment: @G.Smith Here you have a link with the open article http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=1995CeMDA..62...93O&db_key=AST&page_ind=0&plate_select=NO&data_type=GIF&type=SCREEN_GIF&classic=YES

Comment: Using those formulae is a bit challenging because you'd have to write the argument of your dilogarithms for any $x$ as $r\exp(i\phi)$. I tried a few integrals but nothing analytical (that I could manage) so you might have to go numerical. In which case my first plot is a shorter route.

Comment: @SuperCiocia Your answer still says “the difference of these two dilogarithms is real”, which is not true for $x>1/4$.

Comment: RIght sorry, will change it.